# Test execution using N Threads and N2 Loops

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter executed the following test using only one thread Thread group 1: [Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoNIm.png)
In this test there are the following Thread group properties: [Thread Group properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF1zZ.png)
Loop controller configuration: [Loop Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja88p.png)

Accoring to this scenario, Http request GET CustomerDataUpdate should be executed simultaneously using N (50) threads, for each call taking new customer ID from a CSV file (CSV Data Set Config Customers) and Http requests POST StockUpdate and GET PricesUpdate should be executed in parallel in a loop for each Customer N2 (50) times, taking new product ID from a CSV file (CSV Data Set Config Products).

Why my test is executing all the steps only using Thread Group 1 (as shown below) ? [Thread Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO43Z.png)

I am expecting this test to be executed using N (50) Threads simultaneously for N unique Customers and N2 (50) unique Products for each Customer, getting Customer ID and product ID from a CSV files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your test does is:

1. 50 threads and 50 loops in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) mean that `CustomerDataUpdate` will be executed 2500 times
2. After executing the `CustomerDataUpdate` each thread will execute `StockUpdate` and `PricesUpdate` 50 times each due to the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

In total you will have:

- `CustomerDataUpdate` - 2500 times
- `POST StockUpdate` - 125000 times
- `GET PricesUpdate` - 125000 times

Neither `CustomerDataUpdate` nor `StockUpdate` will not be concurrent as [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter) is executing its children in parallel, are you looking for the [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)?

Comment: Thanks, I modified the script in order to meet the initial requirements.